# How To Increase SessionTimeOut

Tags: asp.net

I did by writing this line into web.config

`<sessionState timeout="540"/>`

but My client's Session Expire within 20-40 minute

is there any other way to Increase SessionTimeout for 8-9 hours ?

thanks

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but depending on the number of visitors the site is expecting, I'd be very careful about increasing the session timeout by that much.  Part of the reason for the 20 minutes is to keep server resource useage as low as possible... keeping session information for hours is not going to help that

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could toss something in you global.asax.cs file, to reset the expire.  I'd put it in the Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute method / event.

```
  var cookie = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
  cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
  Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your IIS application pool is recycling. By default it will shut down the worker process after being idle for a certain amount of time.

You could use [SQL Server backed session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx), or you could increase the worker process idle timeout limit.